# iPhone - User location not showing when updated with CLLocation manager on iOS 3.x

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have a mapview which when pushed with its view controller onto the screen shows the location of a
user and some other custom annotations. when the view controller is pushed to screen it calls a function -(void)adduserLocation which shows the location of the user.

I also have a refresh button which also calls -(void)adduserLocation and refreshes all of the annotations and the user location but when the refresh button is pressed the users location does not appear on the map even though all of the same callbacks and updates are being registered (I can see that the user location is received and all the necessary callbacks are made)

I am using :

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil; //for some reason this is only being returned when the view is pushed and the get
                //location method is called but not when the same location method is called     
                //while the view already exists.

 }
```

and:

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

        NSLog(@"User location: %f, %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        currentRegionLat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude; 
        currentRegionLng = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: newLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: newLocation.coordinate.longitude};
        MKCoordinateSpan span = {latitudeDelta: 0.006, longitudeDelta: 0.006};
        MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
        [mView setRegion:region];
        [self getCardsInLocationLat:newLocation.coordinate.latitude andLng:newLocation.coordinate.longitude]; //this is a function which sets the annotations
```

}

I have no idea what I may be doing wrong. Please help. Thanks.

****UPDATE*****
I have managed to find the source of the problem and work around it:
The problem was that I was removing all the annotations on the map before doing a location update
and for some reason the user location annotation was not being added.
So what I did is simply remove only all the non [MKUserLocation class] annotations and left 
the user location annotation. This solved my problem but I still think that either there is some
kind of apple bug here or I am doing something wrong which I cannot yet see.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, why don't you just set the `MKMapView` property, `showsUserLocation`, to `YES`?

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

This way you wouldn't really need to worry about refreshing the location.

If you don't want to use it for battery saving purposes or something, I think we would need to see more of your code. The code that you have doesn't seem to be where the problem lies. Do you get any errors in the console?